# MobileServiceInvalidOperationException is thrown on Xamarin.WindowsPhone 8.1 project

Tags: azure, xamarin, azure-mobile-services, xamarin.winphone

I'm trying to use Azure Mobile Services and Xamarin. I follow all instuctions of official tutorial, created Azure backend for application and downloaded sample quick-start app for Xamarin.Forms from Azure.
There is code in `TodoItemManager.cs`:

```cs
public async Task<ObservableCollection<TodoItem>> GetTodoItemsAsync(bool syncItems = false)
    {
        try
        {
            IEnumerable<TodoItem> items = await todoTable
                .Where(todoItem => !todoItem.Done)
                .ToEnumerableAsync();

            return new ObservableCollection<TodoItem>(items);
        }
        catch (MobileServiceInvalidOperationException msioe)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(@"Invalid sync operation: {0}", msioe.Message);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(@"Sync error: {0}", e.Message);
        }
        return null;
    }
```

And I got `MobileServiceInvalidOperationException` with message "`Invalid sync operation: The request could not be completed.  (Not Found)`". 

I have tested Azure Backend on UWP App and it works fine. So looks like there is problem in WP8.1 project. Can anybody help with this exception?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So.. I forgot to enable internet connection on my Windows Phone